# Income and expense tracker for Android

Tags: gratis, android

I'm looking for a free or a one time paid income and expense tracker android app, not subscription based and not expensive

I tried [vMoneyTracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voutputs.vmoneytracker), it's a bit confusing and [1Money](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pixelrush.moneyiq), I didn't understand how to use it at all. Requirements

- Ability to add multiple income
- Ability to change transaction currency, not all my expenses are in USD
- Ability to add categories
- Ability to tell the app that I transferred some money to my bank account, so that it can tell me what do I have in cash and what is in my bank account
- I do physiotherapy for example, the app should be able to tell me how many physiotherapy sessions I did in a given month and what I spent on it
- Ability to backup to the cloud or sync automatically
- Ability to have a reacquiring expense and income and notification
- Have templates, for example the physiotherapy can be added as an expense template
- Have a simple UI

Comment: Not that I know a fitting recommendation; but while waiting for some, be welcome to take a look at my corresponding app listing: [Budget Planer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/finance_budget) – and, when found a matching app, please [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: @Izzy How much effort have you put into compiling this enormous list? Are you able to make some money out of it or just for fun? Because it has so many items, surprised that a one man can actually do that

Comment: I didn't count the years (started that in a forum originally, then moved to my own site with my own "CMS" so the items at least auto-update). And no, I don't get paid for that – though donations are welcome (see the "support us" link), as well as suggestions on missing apps/sections (https://gitlab.com/IzzyOnDroid/applists). And yes, about 14k apps listed – I manually add them and the links to reviews etc. All else (like the mod warnings, fetching ratings, updating versions) is done automatically by my framework – which I continually improve upon. As I do on my F-Droid repo :)

Comment: @Izzy how can you **manually** add **14k** apps for a **side project**?

Comment: @Lynob it has been a long time since the last time I use [Money Lover](https://moneylover.me/), but I have a good experience with it. I think it satisfies you

Comment: @Ooker the project is running for over 6 years now. So mathematically, it's about 6 apps per day on average :) And yes, one of the main intentions was to help this site and Android.SE.

Comment: @Izzy your boss is a lucky man, he got an employee with an incredible focus and perseverance  in order to keep running such a project for 6 years, many programmers including me kill a project in 3 months max and start another one. I have a short attention span and can be distracted very easily. You could monetize it in some way, you can offer an api for startups that gives them analytics on the competition and marketshare and so on

Comment: @Izzy I met a billion man with a startup idea, lacking the feasibility study and market share study, I spent so many hours looking for statistics, you have a valuable information that startups can use to determine what people like and dislike and what are the competitors and what's their weakness and so on. You could just create an API, since most of the data  needed already exist on your site

Comment: @Lynob we're getting pretty much off-topic here (you can find me in chat if you want to continue this discussion). If someone approaches me with a business request, I'm open to discuss it, of course – but most data is obtained via APIs from other sites (Exodus, Appbrain) anyway. Sure I could provide stats (like how many trackers are in apps, which categories have the most trackers/app-size etc) which I didn't yet see in an API ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stayed with [vMoneyTracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voutputs.vmoneytracker) free version, yes it's a bit confusing and bloated but it has all the features I want, and I already set it up last week before discovering it's bloated so I might just stick with it.

But the real reason I'll still be using it is because they have a blazing fast support, the chat wasn't working, I emailed support, he fixed it, released an update and email me in less than 5 minutes, plus they have a built in chat system within the app, anything I find confusing, I could just chat with the support from within the app, [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpqxNm.jpg).

In short, I don't like the app that much, but I love the support.